# How can we send an AJAX request in controller integration testing rspec/ror?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am sending AJAX request in rspec controller test like following

```
it 'responds with success' do
  xhr :get, :index, delivery_method: :deliver, status: :pending, format: 'js'
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
end
```

but I have no clue how can I send same request in `Integration` testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can send request simply like

```
 xhr 'get','[path_to_action]', delivery_method: :deliver, status: :pending, format: 'js'
```

here `xhr` is a rails request helpers method.